# Health kit - Get shared health data along with my health data

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, healthkit

I can able to get my health data list from health kit. I used below code to get my today's step count :

```
func getTodaysSteps(completion: @escaping (Double) -> Void) {
    
    let stepsQuantityType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .stepCount)!
    
    let now = Date()
    let startOfDay = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: now)
    let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(
        withStart: startOfDay,
        end: now,
        options: .strictStartDate
    )
    
    let query = HKStatisticsQuery(
        quantityType: stepsQuantityType,
        quantitySamplePredicate: predicate,
        options: .cumulativeSum
    ) { _, result, _ in
        guard let result = result, let sum = result.sumQuantity() else {
            completion(0.0)
            return
        }
        completion(sum.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.count()))
    }
    
    healthStore.execute(query)
}
```

But i have one more health data of my brother, where he invited me to see his health data in my real device. Now i was not able to read / get his health data. Is there any way to get that.

Any solution would be great ...!

Answer (score 0):

You don't want a statics query if you want the step count. Try this;

```
     let comp: DateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month], from: Date())
        
     let startOfMonth = Calendar.current.date(from: comp)!
     searchPredicate   = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startOfMonth, end: Date(), options: .strictStartDate)
     let sampleQuery = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: .stepCount, predicate: searchPredicate, limit: limit, sortDescriptors: [])
    {
        (query, result, error) in

        if error != nil
        {
            completion(-1)
        }
        self.hkSampleRecs.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)
       
       
        if result != nil
        {
            for r in result!
            {
                self.hkSampleRecs.append(r)
            }
        }
        completion(self.hkSampleRecs.count)
    }
    
    healthStore.execute(sampleQuery)
```

Note that I haven't shown you the completion setup I used. I'm also storing the records in an array I defined elsewhere (hkSampleRecs). This example also gives data only for this month so far. Change the dates as you need.

Comment: Thanks, Before i was able to get my health data. Only my shared contact health data only i was not able to fetch. How do i get my shared contact health details ?.